# catching error in idiorm and paris orm?

Tags: php, idiorm

I am using paris orm to develop a web application. I am adding data to the database and it fails, when i use a try catch block to catch the error it doesnt work.

My configurations are

```
ORM::configure('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME);
ORM::configure('username',DB_USER);
ORM::configure('password',DB_PASSWORD);
ORM::configure('logging', true);
ORM::configure('error_mode', PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

The insertion code

```
    try {
        $dataToStore                       = SessionData::create();
        $dataToStore->usession_sessioncode = $sessionCode;
        $dataToStore->usessdata_content    = $dataString;
        $dataToStore->save();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Really looked for a solution around but no one gives a clear answer. I want to be to catch the exception and know were the error is exactly.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you are not writing `use PDOException` in your code, so maybe this will help:

```
try {
    $dataToStore                       = SessionData::create();
    $dataToStore->usession_sessioncode = $sessionCode;
    $dataToStore->usessdata_content    = $dataString;
    $dataToStore->save();

} catch (\PDOException $e) { //Added slash
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.